# Trigger something when specific element is clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger an event when a specific item is clicked in this nav-menu.

```
<div class="sidebar-menu">
    
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="sidebar-title">Menu</li>

        <li class="sidebar-item">
            <a href="/" class="sidebar-link active">
                <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="sidebar-item">
            <a href="/Counter" class="sidebar-link">
                <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
                <span>Counter</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="sidebar-item  has-sub">
            <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                <i class="bi bi-stack"></i>
                <span>Components</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu ">
                <li class="submenu-item ">
                    <a href="component-alert.html">Alert</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to run some code whenever a `sidebar-item` is clicked but only if it doesn't contain the has-sub class as well.

This is my current approach:

```
let sidebarEl = document.getElementById("sidebar")
sidebarEl.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if (w <= 991) {
        sidebarEl.classList.remove("active");
    }
});
```

This one works fine when I click anywhere within the sidebar. But how can I limit it to my scenario only?

Comment: `if (!evt.target.closest('.sidebar-item')) `

Comment: How does your code work? I don't see an element with an id of "sidebar".

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `target` element is a list item (`<li>`) and that it does not have the class `has-sub`.

```js
const sidebarMenuEl = document.querySelector('.sidebar-menu');

const onMenuClick = ({ target: { classList, innerText, tagName } }) => {
  if (tagName === 'LI' && !classList.contains('has-sub')) {
    console.log('Clicked on LEAF:', innerText);
  }
};

sidebarMenuEl.addEventListener('click', onMenuClick);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 3rem !important; }

li {
  border: thin dashed red;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="sidebar-title">Menu</li>
    <li class="sidebar-item">
      <a href="/" class="sidebar-link active">
        <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-item">
      <a href="/Counter" class="sidebar-link">
        <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
        <span>Counter</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-item  has-sub">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
        <i class="bi bi-stack"></i>
        <span>Components</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="submenu ">
        <li class="submenu-item ">
          <a href="component-alert.html">Alert</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add your 'click' Event Listener only to the relevant elements by using `document.querySelectorAll(filter)` and specify your Filter as `.sidebar-item:not(.has-sub)`

Example:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-item:not(.has-sub)');
  
  for(var i = 0; i<els.Length; i++){
    var el = els[i];
    el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {      
      //Your code here      
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-menu">
    
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="sidebar-title">Menu</li>

        <li class="sidebar-item">
            <a href="/" class="sidebar-link active">
                <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="sidebar-item">
            <a href="/Counter" class="sidebar-link">
                <i class="bi bi-grid-fill"></i>
                <span>Counter</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="sidebar-item  has-sub">
            <a href="#" class="sidebar-link">
                <i class="bi bi-stack"></i>
                <span>Components</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu ">
                <li class="submenu-item ">
                    <a href="component-alert.html">Alert</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems unnecessary to add an event listener to every element when you can use event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Be careful, you have to use class, not id as selector

```js
let sidebarEl = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-item");
for(item in [...sidebarEl]){
    console.log([...sidebarEl][item]);
    [...sidebarEl][item].addEventListener("click", ev => {
        console.log("add")
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        if (w <= 991) {
            sidebarEl.classList.remove("active");
        }
    });
    
};
```